Problemas con el Carousel de bootstrap dentro de mi proyecto con react
Estoy aprendiendo a usar react y quiero consumir un api para mostrar una imagen y algo de información en un carrusel de Bootstrap, el problema es que cuando intento darle a alguno de los botones no se cambia la imagen y no estoy seguro de cuál es mi error.




Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
